# Marshalling a string on a C++ to C# interface with RGiesecke.DllExport

Tags: c#, interop, unmanaged, dllexport

I have a C# API with an unmanaged C++ interface on top of that.
I created the C++ interface with RGiesecke.DllExport (https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

Now I have problems returning a string from a method call.

I have this C++ interface:

```
_declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl GetName(char* const name, uint32_t* const nameLen);
```

which maps onto this C# method:

```
[DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void GetName(string name, ref UInt32 nameLen)
{
    const string internalName = "abcd";

    name = internalName;
    nameLen = Convert.ToUInt32(internalName.Length);
}
```

The caller at the C++ side is responsible for allocating the memory buffer for the string.

Now the problem is when I call GetName from a C++ program, the buffer to which `name` points doesn't get modified. So the string "abcd" is not passed to the C++ side.

I tried to modify the C# side in several ways:

```
public static void GetName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex=1)] string name, ref UInt32 nameLen)
public static void GetName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)] System.Text.StringBuilder name, ref UInt32 nameLen)
public static void GetName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref System.Text.StringBuilder name, ref UInt32 nameLen)
```

but none of these work.

I prefer to keep the C++ interface unchanged and I have full freedom to change the C# interface.

So: how to pass a string from C# to C++ as a out (or in/out) parameter?

**Update Jul 7 2016:**

I think I am close to the solution.
With the hint from Hans I changed the code into:

```
[DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void GetName(StringBuilder name, ref uint nameLen)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetName(name:{0}, capacity:{1}, maxCapacity:{2}, length:{3})",
        name, name.Capacity, name.MaxCapacity, nameLen);

    const string internalName = "abcd";

    name.Append(internalName);
    nameLen = Convert.ToUInt32(internalName.Length);
}
```

This still doesn't work, but eventually I get into the GetName method. There I get a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when calling the StringBuilder. This is the output in my console:

```
GetName(name:, capacity:0, maxCapacity:0, length:0)

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: capacity was less than the current size.
Parameter name: requiredLength
    at System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32 requiredLength)
    at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(String value)
    at Omron.Sysmac.Ipc.Api.IpcSystemApi.GetName(StringBuilder name, UInt32& nameLen)
```

Now I think the character buffer is not marshalled correctly to the StringBuilder. I would expect a Stringbuilder with a proper capacity.

For completeness, here is my C code:

```
extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl GetName(char* name, unsigned int* length);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char buffer[256] = { 0, };
    unsigned int length = 0;
    GetName(buffer, &length);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: System.String is immutable, it needs to be StringBuilder.  And you *do* need to verify if the passed-in *nameLen* argument is large enough, corrupting the stack of a native program is never a good idea.  And you'd better consider some way to report invalid usage, an *int* return value that represents an error code would be wise.  Now the native code can discover how large a buffer is required by calling your function twice, normally done by passing a NULL as the first argument.  Details that matter to a good api.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try to use StringBuilder. You are right about the length check and reporting the error. I intentionally left that out for simplicity here.